# File cabinet drawer falls out

Tags: safety

[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrP4L.jpg)One drawer falls out when roller slides are extended. I cannot see what is supposed to stop it.  The hems on the sides of the drawer near the bottom (Left side of pic 1) are smooth.  There is a tilted flange on the slide (just to the left of the rollers in pic 2).  This is the same on the other drawers which stop when extended to that flange.  One has to lift up on the drawers to remove them. I cannot see what stops them.

Comment: You said one drawer, I imagine there are others in cabinet that don't fall out.  Remove one or more drawers and compare to the one that falls.  You should find something worn down, bent, or missing on drawers or slides.

Comment: Provide the photo of the slide on the drawer. I think the tilted flange is attached to the wheels through a spring (like a hairpin) which will lock the drawer from falling out. The locking mechanism is engaged through something affixed on the slide on the drawer, then push to lock.

Comment: Thanks for quickly responding.  Photos of the slide showing the flange and the side of the drawer are attached to the original post.  There does not seem to be any difference in the hems of the other drawers, which are all smooth for their entire length.  The slides appear, to me, to be identical.  There aren't any springs or pins.  I cannot see what is supposed to stop the drawer on any of them, yet the other three drawers do lock when fully extended.

Comment: If I were designing this, I might have had something on the underside of the hem which would hook on to the flange.